# Vim: Delete everything in a line but the numbers

Tags: vim

I want to delete everything in a line but numbers. I have a line that looks like this:

```
a b c d 12 k f h 10
```

I want the output to be

```
1210
```

I tried

```
:%s/\d+\@!//
```

but nothing happens, although all the text that should be deleted will be marked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better ask at http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: mhh, the other forum does not seem to be used that much, but generally i agree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
:%s/\D//g
```

It should delete all non digits.

Comment: thanks wallyk, that is what I wanted, because with your solution i can easily extend it to other problems.